# Fill a custom image from bottom to top in react native

Tags: react-native

I want this apple image to fill from bottom to top but could not find a solution. I have used tint color for this but it fills the whole image.

```
<Image source={require('../images/Apple.png')}
                  style={{
                             height: hp('20%'),
                             width: wp('30%'),
                             tintColor:'red'
                                   }}
 />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with adding resizeMode prop to the image component.

Like.

```
<Image
    source={require('../images/Apple.png')}
    style={{
        height: hp('20%'),
        width: wp('30%'),
        tintColor:'red'
    }}
    resizeMode="cover"
/>
```